# C++ -- How write a function, that return the derivative of a real valued function, not the value of the derivative

Tags: c++

This function calculates the value of the Derivation of the Function Foo at X

```
double Deriv( double(* Foo)(double x), double X )
{
    const double mtDx = 1.0e-6;

    double x1 = Foo(X+mtDx);
    double x0 = Foo(X);

    return ( x1 - x0 ) / mtDx;
}
```

I would like to write a Funktion, which returned not the value of the derivation at X, but a new function which IS the derivation of the function Foo.

```
 xxxx Deriv( double(* Foo)(double x) )
{
    return Derivation of Foo;
}
```

Then it would be possible to write 
SecondDeriv = Deriv( Deriv( Foo ))

Is it possible in C++ according to new standard to write such a function ?
I think with old standard it was impossible.

Comment: Not for a general function , no ...

Comment: It is impossible in general because C++ functions are not mathematical functions.

Comment: You want to write the derivative function on the fly?  Good luck.  Maybe a lambda can be used, but otherwise, you're out of luck.  My guess is "out of luck", but I'm not sufficiently confident in my understanding of lambdas to be definitive about that.

Comment: No, you have to get a better understanding of what function pointers actually represent. Upvoted for the em-dash in the title though!

Comment: You certainly can't get analytical derivation without a DSL, but what you can do is create a function that does numerical differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you can compute the value of a function at one point, you can use that to implement your general function. Lambda expressions allow you to generate those derived functions easily:

```
auto MakeDerivative(double (&f)(double)) {
  return [=](double x) { return Deriv(f, x); };
}
```

If you want to be able to use stateful functions, you may need to update your `Deriv` to be a function template whose first parameter type is a template parameter. This is true in particular if you want to apply `MakeDerivative` repeatedly (since its return types are stateful closures):

```
template <typename F>
double Deriv(F f, double x) {
  // your code here
}

template <typename F>
auto MakeDerivative(F f) {
  return [=](double x) { return Deriv(f, x); };
}
```

However, you may be interested in techniques like "automatic differentiation" which allow you to express the derivative directly in terms of the definition of the original function, at the cost of working on an enlarged domain (an infinitesimal neighbourhood, essentially).

Comment: [Demo with `sin`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hKKnaPcBRjtohB5V). [demo with a cubic polynomial](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bKx0tMVyveTITO1H).

Comment: (Demo [with coordinate axes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3R17jxGcoPqXHnDC) because OCD.)

Comment: thanks for your very well-grounded answer and the demos! I need some to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<double(double)> Deriv( double(*Foo)(double x) )
{
   auto f = [Foo](double x) -> double 
   {
      const double mtDx = 1.0e-6;

      double x1 = Foo(x+mtDx);
      double x0 = Foo(x);

      return ( x1 - x0 ) / mtDx;
   };

   return f;
}

double Foo(double x)
{
   return x*x;
}

double Bar(double x)
{
   return x*x*x;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << Deriv(Foo)(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << Deriv(Bar)(10) << std::endl;
}
```

---

Output:

```
20
300
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to complete your program with the second derivations.

Answer (score 1):

Using generic lambda, implementing a toy `derivative` is simple. In the following code, `derivative` is a derivative operator in the math sense. It accepts a function `double -> double`, produces its derivative `double -> double`.

```
#include <iostream>

double delta = 0.001;

auto derivative = [] ( auto foo ) {
    return [foo] (double x) { 
        // the simplest formula for numeric derivative
        return (foo(x + delta) - foo(x)) / delta;
    };
};

// test
int main() {
    auto quar = [] ( double x ) { return x * x; };
    auto dev_quar = derivative(quar);
    auto dev_dev_quar = derivative(dev_quar);

    for ( double s = 0.0; s < 10.0; ++s ) {
        std::cout << "(" << quar(s) << "," << dev_quar(s) << "," << dev_dev_quar(s) << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program runs perfectly. I will try to complete it for the second derivations.